# How to ensure images load before generating PDF?

Tags: php, curl, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have a PHP loop that does the following:

1. Log in to a web page via CURL
2. Capture and internal page that requires a login
3. Save the HTML of the page to a local file
4. Using WKHTMLTOPDF, render the page as a PDF

The issue I'm having is that every once in a while (maybe ~30% of the time), the images won't render in the PDF. If I open up one of the saved HTML files, I'll find that I need to go in and manually refresh the page for the images to show up.

Any ideas on how to pragmatically ensure the images load? Things I've tried:

1. `sleep(n)` between each and every line
2. Adding `--javascript-delay 30000` to my WKHTMLTOPDF call to ensure it has ample time to load any images.

#1 made it considerably worse, and #2 did nothing at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the image references in the local HTML still valid? So, you'd have to grab every image from the remote server and copy it to the right place locally. I'm wondering if it would be easier to get a valid cookie (via CURL etc) and then supply this to wkhtmltopdf, which then goes directly to the remote authenticated page?

Comment: wkhtmltopdf actually has a method for generating a cookie, but it was a nightmare to get working in this particular situation (hence the CURL route). When I read in the HTML I'm replacing all the paths to the remote image path, which definitely works since I can open the HTML file and hard refresh to see the images, it's like there just isn't enough oomph to get the image every time. Worst case I guess I can try to get that cookie working with wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: For an alternate approach, you could try using `wget` with its `--page-requisites` and `--convert-links` options to download the HTML/CSS/Images to a local location, altering links at the same time. Then just run the PDF renderer against the local copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between step 3 & 4 of your example you might want to consider parsing the HTML file for all image links and downloading them individually using curl, saving them locally as well and then updating the links in the saved HTML file to point to the new local image resources instead of the remote ones.

This should drastically improve the load time of images when rendering the HTML as a PDF.

Comment: Thanks, Steve - this is what I wound up doing and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

What if after you scrape the html with cURL, have php loop through each img element and read in the image file binary data and replace the image src url attribute with the base64 encode value of the opened image file like:

`'<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'. base64_encode($imagedata) . '"/>'`

if the base64 image data is hardcoded into the page than that would give you a programmatic way to verify all pictures are "loaded" and prevent the issue of the pdf conversion starting before all pictures had downloaded...

Comment: this requires a fresh layout just for pdf rendering using views. not much practice. with many images, even easier to hit php mem limit.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this but maybe you can find out whether the download is done by iterally calling `curl_getinfo()` and then reading out the values for `CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD` - until that value doesn't change anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you add a onLoad to the images you need to know that are loading? something like

```
<img src='foo.jpg' onLoad='callbackFuncion();'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could process the downloaded HTML, searching for img tags, then dowloading the images to a local storage and replacing the src attribute. That way, you should be generating the pdf after all the images are available.